# How to make input to be in correct format

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple car speeding test system, where I could input the car numbers and then make forward steps. So what I need for now is the format of the car numbers. In Lithuania car number formats are "XXX 123", and I need this as a correct input in the system `Car_numb = input("Input car number: ABC123 ")` How could i make the input to accept only inputs as ABC123,OFD612?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use solution involving regular expressions. In python there's a lib `re` - it can compile regex and check if the passed string matches it.
So as for your example i'm gonna use this regex:

```
^[A-Z]{3}\d{3}$
```

Where ^ - beginning of the string, [A-Z] - capital letter, {3} - exactly 3 letters, \d - digit, also {3} times. $ - that's the string's end.

So using code below you can check if your string matches the car number format you presented.

```py
    import re
    car_numb_re = re.compile(r'^[A-Z]{3}\d{3}$')

    car_numb = input("Input car number:")

    if car_numb_re.match(car_numb):
       # matches!
       pass
```

Besides, there's a great tool you can use to write and check your regexes. It explains every part of the regex you have typed in. https://regex101.com/r/QojYEt/1

Comment: please specify your python version and what excpetion you get

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. First step would be [linking this awesome tool](https://regex101.com/r/QojYEt/1). After that, adding explanation to the answer itself would prevent any confusion or missing information in case the link dies.

Comment: Sahsahae, sounds good :) adding some more information to the answer

Comment: Can I ask how to add a space between XXX 123 in regex? \s ?

Comment: Does you car number format is 'ACB 123' - with space between? Or it can be both with and without space?